# CFNetwork / AppleJPEG crash

Tags: ios, crash, report, cfnetwork

I am trying to debug this crash report - it occurred when attempting an image upload (I cannot replicate the crash myself) I usually get a particular line of code that the app crashes on - how would I go about debugging something like this?

```
Incident Identifier: 3E611C97-5E8D-4BB7-AE32-C79B0E546B8C
CrashReporter Key:   82bbb5c63aa617e1844c55474133c93210710452
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:             - [837]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BCDBACC6-99E7-48A4-B83B-E7DE194F34BA/-.app/-
Identifier:          -
Version:             2 (1.02)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-04-19 16:23:03.03 +0100
Launch Time:         2016-04-19 16:22:29.29 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.1 (13E238)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x180b22e38 0x180187f80 0x180a0b83c 0x180a0b6d4 0x10012de40 0x100256768 0x18056d4bc 0x18056d47c 0x180572b84 0x180ad8dd8 0x180ad6c40 0x180a00d10 0x1822e8088 0x185cd5f70 0x1002697a8 0x18059e8b8)

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.998330     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181105a44 TCP Conn 0x136c9dfd0 SSL Handshake DONE
1.152285     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181105954 TCP Conn 0x136c9dfd0 starting SSL negotiation
1.152870     CFNetwork                  0x00000001811a7da4 TCP Conn 0x136c9dfd0 complete. fd: 22, err: 0
1.154239     CFNetwork                  0x00000001811a92d0 TCP Conn 0x136c9dfd0 event 1. err: 0
1.238837     CFNetwork                  0x00000001811a93a8 TCP Conn 0x136c9dfd0 started
3.689568     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181105a44 TCP Conn 0x136c5bd90 SSL Handshake DONE
3.831493     CFNetwork                  0x0000000181105954 TCP Conn 0x136c5bd90 starting SSL negotiation
3.831860     CFNetwork                  0x00000001811a7da4 TCP Conn 0x136c5bd90 complete. fd: 22, err: 0
3.833126     CFNetwork                  0x00000001811a92d0 TCP Conn 0x136c5bd90 event 1. err: 0
3.922535     CFNetwork                  0x00000001811a93a8 TCP Conn 0x136c5bd90 started
6.363157     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x136260400] Created session
12.888703    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x1361c7a00] Releasing session
12.897088    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x1361cfa00] Releasing session
12.897088    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x1361cfa00] Created session
12.897088    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x1361c7a00] Created session
12.937792    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x13592ce00] Releasing session
12.938071    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182584f28 [0x13592ce00] Decoding completed without errors
12.938873    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001825830c0 [0x13592ce00] Options: 136x136 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
12.938873    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582f78 [0x13592ce00] Decoding: C0 0x00880088 0x0000304A 0x11111100 0x00000000 1572
12.938873    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x135936200] Releasing session
12.938873    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x135936200] Created session
12.938873    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x13592ce00] Created session
12.952696    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x135931200] Releasing session
12.993090    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x135939a00] Releasing session
12.993090    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x135939a00] Created session
12.993090    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x135931200] Created session
13.028701    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x1361c8c00] Releasing session
13.030162    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182584f28 [0x1361c8c00] Decoding completed without errors
13.030590    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001825830c0 [0x1361c8c00] Options: 136x136 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
13.030590    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582f78 [0x1361c8c00] Decoding: C0 0x00880088 0x0000304A 0x11111100 0x00000000 1572
13.030626    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x1361cf000] Releasing session
13.031088    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x1361cf000] Created session
13.031088    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x1361c8c00] Created session
13.148926    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x13591c600] Releasing session
13.149708    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182584f28 [0x13591c600] Decoding completed without errors
13.149708    AppleJPEG                  0x00000001825830c0 [0x13591c600] Options: 136x136 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
13.149708    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582f78 [0x13591c600] Decoding: C0 0x00880088 0x0000304A 0x11111100 0x00000000 1572
13.149708    AppleJPEG                  0x0000000182582a88 [0x13592fe00] Releasing session
13.149918    AppleJPEG                  0x000000018258226c [0x13592fe00] Created session



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bc11c 0x1806a0000 + 114972
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180788ef8 0x180784000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018062de4c 0x1805cc000 + 400972
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018062ddb8 0x1805cc000 + 400824
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001801613f4 0x180160000 + 5108
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018017de98 0x180160000 + 122520
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180188248 0x180180000 + 33352
7   -                           0x00000001004a89e0 0x1000c8000 + 4065760
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018017af44 0x180160000 + 110404
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018017a85c 0x180160000 + 108636
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180188094 0x180180000 + 32916
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a0b83c 0x1809f8000 + 79932
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a0b6d4 0x1809f8000 + 79572
13  -                           0x000000010012de40 0x1000c8000 + 417344
14  -                           0x0000000100256768 0x1000c8000 + 1632104
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018056d4bc 0x18056c000 + 5308
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018056d47c 0x18056c000 + 5244
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180572b84 0x18056c000 + 27524
18  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad8dd8 0x1809f8000 + 921048
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad6c40 0x1809f8000 + 912448
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a00d10 0x1809f8000 + 36112
21  GraphicsServices                0x00000001822e8088 0x1822dc000 + 49288
22  UIKit                           0x0000000185cd5f70 0x185c58000 + 515952
23  -                           0x00000001002697a8 0x1000c8000 + 1709992
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018059e8b8 0x18059c000 + 10424

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bd4d8 0x1806a0000 + 120024
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001805807d8 0x18056c000 + 83928
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018056f648 0x18056c000 + 13896

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 4 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0fd8 0x1806a0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0e54 0x1806a0000 + 3668
2   -                           0x0000000100496ed8 0x1000c8000 + 3993304
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787b28 0x180784000 + 15144
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787a8c 0x180784000 + 14988
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785028 0x180784000 + 4136

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0fd8 0x1806a0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0e54 0x1806a0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad8ce8 0x1809f8000 + 920808
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad69ec 0x1809f8000 + 911852
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a00d10 0x1809f8000 + 36112
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000181181af4 0x1810d4000 + 711412
6   Foundation                      0x00000001814f7e1c 0x181404000 + 998940
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787b28 0x180784000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787a8c 0x180784000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785028 0x180784000 + 4136

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bc344 0x1806a0000 + 115524
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180adf250 0x1809f8000 + 946768
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787b28 0x180784000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787a8c 0x180784000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785028 0x180784000 + 4136

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0fd8 0x1806a0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0e54 0x1806a0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad8ce8 0x1809f8000 + 920808
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad69ec 0x1809f8000 + 911852
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a00d10 0x1809f8000 + 36112
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x00000001871699e0 0x187124000 + 285152
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x000000018713e75c 0x187124000 + 108380
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787b28 0x180784000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787a8c 0x180784000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785028 0x180784000 + 4136

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 9 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0fd8 0x1806a0000 + 4056
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806a0e54 0x1806a0000 + 3668
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad8ce8 0x1809f8000 + 920808
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180ad69ec 0x1809f8000 + 911852
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180a00d10 0x1809f8000 + 36112
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181410d8c 0x181404000 + 52620
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181465ff8 0x181404000 + 401400
7   -                           0x000000010021e51c 0x1000c8000 + 1402140
8   Foundation                      0x00000001814f7e1c 0x181404000 + 998940
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787b28 0x180784000 + 15144
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180787a8c 0x180784000 + 14988
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785028 0x180784000 + 4136

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001806bcb48 0x1806a0000 + 117576
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785530 0x180784000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180785020 0x180784000 + 4128

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x00000000ffffffff  x15: 0x00000000fffffff2
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019eb8f000  x21: 0x000000016fd354d0  x22: 0x0000000000000006  x23: 0x000000010055f1a4
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x00000001368aa000  x26: 0x00000001355e9790  x27: 0x0000000136c00e40
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016fd353f0   lr: 0x0000000180788ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd353d0   pc: 0x00000001806bc11c cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, based on "EXC_CRASH" it looks like your app hit an uncaught exception somewhere. The crash is on your main thread.

You will need to symbolicate this crash in order to see the method names instead of memory addresses. You will need the .dSYM file generated for this exact build of your application and the matching binary in order to do this, otherwise all you can symbolicate are the system/framework calls.

If Xcode has the matching .dSYM file and binary, it can do it automatically for you.

From Apple TN2151:

> Xcode will automatically symbolicate all crash reports that it encounters, if it has the .dSYM and application binary that produced the crash report. Given a crash report, the matching binary, and its .dSYM file, all you need to do for symbolication is to add the crash report to the Xcode Organizer.

For more details (and step by step on symbolication) see TN2151's section on symbolication: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-STACKTRACE